# how to get valid latitude and longitude from linestring

Tags: geopandas, shapefile, multilinestring

I want a list of latitudes and longitudes of North Carolina roads for my research work. So I got the .shp file from here
https://xfer.services.ncdot.gov/gisdot/DistDOTData/NCRoutes_SHP.zip

and I loaded the file using geopandas.

```html
import geopandas as gpd
graph = gpd.read_file("NCRoutes.shp")
```

Here is the geometry column of the shapefile.

```html
graph['geometry']
```

Output:

```html
0         MULTILINESTRING Z ((950413.442 761781.527 0.00...
1         MULTILINESTRING Z ((947047.370 633980.630 2181...
2         MULTILINESTRING Z ((946481.250 821340.560 3756...
3         LINESTRING Z (1000455.242 564424.433 1854.400,...
4         LINESTRING Z (1840729.024 842228.554 588.800, ...
                                ...                        
373365    LINESTRING Z (2474108.250 658112.370 67.400, 2...
373366    LINESTRING Z (2331115.610 180293.340 37.400, 2...
373367    LINESTRING Z (2398439.990 968349.560 156.400, ...
373368    LINESTRING Z (1465953.417 567437.417 810.200, ...
373369    LINESTRING Z (1782694.744 871896.463 833.000, ...
Name: geometry, Length: 373370, dtype: geometry
```

When I print a single linestring, it looks like this-

```html
graph['geometry'][3].coords.xy
```

Output:

```html
(array('d', [1000455.2419360131, 1000541.414176017, 1000666.0802560151, 1000866.2999680042, 1001138.8699360043, 1001250.1976800114, 1001361.2661760151, 1001444.3955520093, 1001527.3755040169, 1001610.2039200068, 1001692.8797440082,.....
```

how do I convert these multistring and linestrings to latitudes and longitudes?

Answer (score 0):

You need to [transform  your geometries to a geographic coordinate system.](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_crs.html). Let's use the poplar WGS 84. But first of all, let's check to see that the data has a CRS defined. Printing the `gdf.crs` attribute on our gdf lets us know that the data are currently in a NC State Plane projected coordinate system. Hint: This can also be deduced by looking at the .prj file where it's stored in WKT(well-known text) format. You can also find this information in QGIS, ArcGIS, etc.

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('NCRoutes.shp')

gdf.crs
```

Next we can use gpd's .to_crs() to convert to WGS 84, which uses EPSG code 4326.

```
gdf_wgs84 = gdf.to_crs(4326)
```

Let's look at the first few geometry rows. As you can see the coordinates are no longer measured in feet, but are now longitude and latitude.

```
gdf_wgs84['geometry'].head()
```

Output:

```
0    MULTILINESTRING ((-82.53992 35.79168, -82.5399...
1    MULTILINESTRING ((-82.53591 35.44045, -82.5358...
2    MULTILINESTRING ((-82.56037 35.95481, -82.5603...
3    LINESTRING (-82.34883 35.25454, -82.34854 35.2...
4    LINESTRING (-79.53887 36.06291, -79.53876 36.0...
Name: geometry, dtype: geometry
```